# Unable to iterate json array in for each loop using velocity template

Tags: arrays, json, foreach, velocity, velocity-template-language

I have a json like this :

```
{
"name" : "xyz",
"age" : "12",
"familyprofile" : 
[{"name" :"abc", "Occupation":"manager","age":"30" },{"name" :"def","Occupation":"housewife","age":"30"}]
}
```

i am trying to print family profiles in table using velocity template.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>name</b></td>
<td><b>Occupation</b></td>
<td><b>age</b></td>
</tr>
#set($steps = {$headers.familyprofile})
#foreach($step in $steps)
<tr>
<td>step.name</td>
<td>step.Occupation</td>
<td>step.age</td>
</tr>
#end
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax problem, you should use:

```
#set($steps = $headers.familyprofile)
```

or:

```
#set($steps = ${headers.familyprofile})
```

Comment: it was typo i used ${headers.familyprofile}.....it dosent work

Comment: Please print `$headers.familyprofile`, `$headers.familyprofile.class.name` and `$headers.familyprofile.size()` to help us understand what happens.